# Looping through selected values in R

Tags: r, loops

I want to iterate a loop only for some values so I am using this:

```
present <- c(3,5,7,8)
for(i in present)
{
   print(i)
}
```

which gives me

```
[1] 3
[1] 5
[1] 7
[1] 8
```

however I need to jump to the next value within the loop, say I dont want 5 to be printed in above example.

I cannot use next since I want it in nested for like this

```
present <- c(3,5,7,8)
for(i in present)
{
    k <- i
    "Jump to next value of present"
    while(k < "The next value for i should come here")
    {
        k <- k + 1
        print(k)
    }
}
```

The output would be 3 4 5 6 7 8 but the condition must check value of k if it exceeds next value of i.

Is there anyway to accomplish this?

I'll take help of C to explain further,

```
for(i=0; i < 10; i++)
{
   for(k=i;k <= i+1;k++)
   {
       printf("%d", k);
   }
}
```

The link contains output of above code
http://codepad.org/relkenY3

It is easy in C since next value is in sequence, but here next value is not known, hence the problem.

Comment: Why is 5 being skipped in particular? Do you want to avoid printing all the items that meet some condition, every second item, or what's the logic for when things should and shouldn't be printed?

Comment: The first example was to elaborate my need, however in next example you can see I want to print values that are less than next value of i so jump to next in sequence

Comment: It is not at all clear what you want to be printed.  Please be specific.

Comment: I think you are looking for something like `mapply(seq, head(present, -1) + 1, tail(present, -1))`.

Comment: @flodel yeah that is pretty much what I want. Please elaborate the answer. Thanks a lot

Comment: @MatthewLundberg is it clear after the edit I made

Comment: Actually, no it is not.  `seq(min(present), max(present))` prints those values, but is almost certainly not what you are after.  Seems @flodel can discern what you are after.  Better man than I.

Comment: If you fix this question so that it makes sense, I'll remove my downvote.

Comment: @MatthewLundberg I tried my best, hope it's clear now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you should do is loop through two vectors:

```
x <- head(present, -1)
# [1] 3 5 7
y <- tail(present, -1)
# [1] 5 7 8
```

and the function to do that is `mapply` (have a look at `?mapply`). A close translation of your pseudo-code would be:

```
invisible(mapply(function(x, y) while(x < y) {x <- x + 1; print(x)}, x, y))
```

but maybe you'll find this more interesting:

```
mapply(seq, x + 1, y)
```

Comment: Thanks again, Superb logic

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the answer is to use `seq_along` and use it as an index into "present", but as others have pointed out your code does not promise to deliver what you expect, even with that simple modification. The `K <- K=1` assignment jumps ahead too far to deliver a value of 3 at any point and the termination condition is likewise not clear.  It turns into an infinite loop in the form you construct. Work with this;

```
present <- c(3,5,7,8)
    for(i in seq_along(present))
    {
        k <- i
        while(k < length(present) )
        {
            k <- k + 1
            print(present[k])
        }
    }
```